# How do I setup/connect a Mac Book Pro OSX to a Windows domain over VPN

Tags: mac-osx, vpn, active-directory

In windows I am able to do this by logging in as a local user, connecting to VPN, doing the initial domain connection (which includes creating a new user which is my domain account), then leaving that user logged in I "switch user" to the user I setup just prior and it is able to cache my login token from the VPN connected on the local user. I can then logout/login with my domain user without the local user being logged in.

I can connect to the domain in System Preferences->Accounts->Network Account Server: Join, and it says i'm connected, but it looks like I still have to go into the Accounts to connect each time..

How can I do this in OSX 10.6?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your problem well. If I'm guessing correctly the problem is that OSX does not cache your AD credentials, then there is the option in the advanced settings in OSX where you enable Mobile Accounts for AD. This means that OSX will cache the user's credentials when they first login.

Unfortunately I don't have a Mac before me at the moment but maybe this will help http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=serveradmin/10.4/en/c7od48.html

Comment: My issue is that I can not login with my domain (AD) credentials in the first place.  I'll take a look at that post, play around and see if it helps.  Thanks for the lead.